# Sorting Range in VBA function without affecting data in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, linear-interpolation

I am creating a linear interpolation function in VBA. Here is what it looks like:

```
Function INTERP(X0 As Variant, ByVal X As Range, ByVal Y As Range) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim N As Long
    Dim X1 As Double
    Dim X2 As Double
    Dim Y1 As Double
    Dim Y2 As Double

    N = X.Rows.Count

    If X0 <= Application.Min(X) Then
        X2 = X.Cells(2, 1)
        Y2 = Y.Cells(2, 1)
        X1 = X.Cells(1, 1)
        Y1 = Y.Cells(1, 1)
    ElseIf X0 >= Application.Max(X) Then
        X2 = X.Cells(N, 1)
        Y2 = Y.Cells(N, 1)
        X1 = X.Cells(N - 1, 1)
        Y1 = Y.Cells(N - 1, 1)
    Else
        For i = 1 To N - 1
            If X0 >= X.Cells(1, 1) And X0 < X.Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
                X2 = X.Cells(i + 1, 1)
                Y2 = Y.Cells(i + 1, 1)
                X1 = X.Cells(i, 1)
                Y1 = Y.Cells(i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    INTERP = Y1 + (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1) * (X0 - X1)

End Function
```

In order to perform the interpolation the `X` range should be sorted in ascending order. Most of the other answers relating to sorting in Excel VBA that I've seen deal with doing some kind of sorting that goes back and sorts the data in the worksheet.

In this case **I don't want to alter the data in the worksheet** at all, but I need to sort `X` in ascending order then sort `Y` based on `X` to preserve the relationship between them. How can I do this with VBA?

Comment: Load it into an array and then sort that using any of the myriad sorting algorithms, like Quick Sort, Bubble Sort etc.

Comment: @Rory I saw that Ranges have a `Range.sort` method already implemented for sorting. Is there a sort function for this in VBA? All I can seem to find is code to implement the sorting methods. I can include this in my project but it seems like a headache to have to re-implement these.

Comment: No, you have to write your own, or just copy the data to another range, sort it and then load it back.

Answer (score 0):

Save `X` and `Y` as a table (it could even be a table with no formatting).
Then just sort the table, the rest of the sheet will stay the same.